# What does this <xsl:apply-templates select="*/doc"/> mean?

Tags: xml, xslt

While analyzing some xslt program I fond out the below code

<'xsl:apply-templates select="*/doc"/>

What does the above xslt mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"apply-templates" defines which template shall be performed next (see spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Applying-Template-Rules)
"*/doc" defines which element triggers the template (see spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev), in this case: select the children elements named "doc" of all element children of the context node.